# Vectorization in Octave

Tags: octave, vectorization

I have to vectorize the following code in Octave:

```
y(1) = 0;
for a = 2:length(x)
    y(a) = y(a-1) + quad(@(x) 1./x .- 1./x.^2 .+ 1./x.^3, x(a-1), x(a));
endfor
```

I've tried to do

```
y = cumtrapz(x,dx);
```

Where x and dx are both vectors, but cumptrapz is not precise enough. If I make the vectors bigger (x and y are both a vector of 12000 doubles) to get more precision, Octave runs out of memory.

Comment: Shouldn't `f` be a function handle? Edit the question with sample input and expected output? When you said `".. If I make the vectors bigger.."`, so what's the datasize you are using?

Comment: Yes, `f` is a function handle. `x`  and `y` are both 12000 double vectors

Comment: Try initializing `y` with `y = zeros(size(x))` and see if this helps? Thus, replace `y(1) = 0;` with `y = zeros(size(x))`.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. It might be a precision issue. How can I increase precision without making the vectors too big?

Comment: If you asking which function to use for better precision, I don't think I have much of ideas on that.

Comment: It was a precision issue. `cumtrapz` is less precise than `quad`.